# Elm Markdown Block Highlighting

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock, elm

Is there an off-the-shelf solution for highlighting the `[markdown| ... |]` blocks in Elm code?

At the moment I'm using `haskell-mode` to edit Elm files, and have [`two-mode-mode`](http://www.welton.it/freesoftware/files/two-mode-mode.el) hooked up to switch to `markdown-mode` when I enter an appropriate block with

```lisp
(require 'two-mode-mode)
(setq default-mode (list "Haskell" 'haskell-mode)
      second-modes (list (list "Markdown" "\[markdown|" "|\]" 'markdown-mode)))
```

Ideally, there would be a solution that just highlighted everything at once in the same buffer, keeping the appropriate regions in `markdown-mode`, but wasn't as complicated to set up as [this](http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/haskell-latex.el) seems to be.

Comment: You're probably not willing to switch editors, but I wrote tmLanguage files for Sublime Text [here](https://github.com/deadfoxygrandpa/Elm.tmLanguage) that do what you want

Comment: @deadfoxygrandpa - I wouldn't mind trying it, but I can't see a license anywhere on [that site](http://www.sublimetext.com/). How is Sublime's source released?

Comment: It's a closed source commercial program with an unlimited length, unrestricted trial version

Comment: @deadfoxygrandpa - That settles that then. No, I'm not willing to switch from a GPL-licensed editor to a non-Free one.

Comment: Fair enough, I figured as much once you asked about the source.

Comment: The Emacs Wiki has a Markdown solution, which should be easy enough to just convert the relevant portion over to haskell-mode for the font-lock highlighting that you seek.  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MarkdownMode

Answer (score 1):

You can import deadfoxygrandpa's [Elm.tmLanguage](https://raw.github.com/deadfoxygrandpa/Elm.tmLanguage/master/Syntax%20Highlighting/Elm.tmLanguage) into [Ace](http://ace.c9.io), the open-source web-based editor as described [here](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Importing-.tmtheme-and-.tmlanguage-Files-into-Ace).